# Как откатиться назад на стабильный commit и при этом сохранить полезный код, который ты сделал после допущенной ошибки?

Tags: git, git-commit, контроль-версий

Недавно я начал знакомство с GIT и у меня возник вопрос.

Представим такую ситуацию.

**День 1.** Я создал файл script.js.  Написал немного кода. Проверил, чтобы всё было без ошибок. Сделал commit.
Теперь у меня есть стабильный файл script.js. Если что-то случится в будущем, то я могу откатиться на этот commit.

**День 2.** Вот я снова начал писать код в файл script.js и допустил незаметную ошибку, из-за которой в будущем могут возникнуть серьезные проблемы и которую нельзя просто так исправить. Из-за этой ошибки в любом случае придётся откатывать проект снова на "***День 1***". Но сейчас я про это не знаю, поэтому довольный делаю commit.

**День 3.** На следующий день, я снова начал работать с файлом script.js. Написал **ПОЛЕЗНЫЙ** код, сделал commit.
И так я работал в течении нескольких дней. После "***День 2***", когда я допустил фатальную ошибку, я еще написал очень много **ПОЛЕЗНОГО** кода в "***День 3***", "***День 4***" и т.д.  Добавил много разных фич и т.д.

Вот в определенный момент я обнаруживаю, что оказывается когда-то я допустил ошибку. И теперь придётся откатываться к стабильному commit. Но из-за этой ошибки пропадает много полезного кода. Как быть в такой ситуации?
***День 1, 2, 3*** это лишь пример для упрощения ситуации. Подобная проблема может возникнуть на любой стадии разработки.
Как откатиться назад на стабильный commit и при этом сохранить полезный код, который ты сделал после допущенной ошибки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А зачем вообще откатываться? Что мешает просто взять и исправить ошибку?

Comment: я понял, автор хочет втулить коммит в середину истории, что бы поправить багу прям по месту. В целом это возможно (например. можно сделать коммит, а потом через rebase подвинуть его в нужное место. при этом скорее всего нужно будет решить кучу конфликтов, а также потеряются хеши новых коммитов) А можно просто через cherry-pick собрать себе нужную ветку, убедится, что она правильная и потом подменить main/master. Но по факту это все равно первый способ. Очень похоже, что автор хочет систему контроля версий на базе дифов.

Comment: Вывод из этой ситуации должен быть "не писать ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО полезного кода в одном файле". А вообще еще можно попробовать сделать реверт коммита с плохими изменениями вместо полного откатывания. @KoVadim Дак git и есть система контроля версия на базе дифов.

Comment: @user7860670 нет, git хранит объекты из всех коммитов целиком, дифы вычисляются на лету только при вызове команды "git diff" и подобных

Comment: @user7860670 это распространённое заблуждение о дифах. Хотя есть паки, где как раз могут хранится изменения в виде дифов.

Comment: @andreymal Как он там реально хранит - совершенно не важно, важно, что информацию о различиях можно получить.

Comment: @user7860670 О, уже не важно:)

Comment: @KoVadim Конечно не важно

Comment: @user7860670 просто теперь мне понятно, что git для Вас просто черный ящик.

Comment: @KoVadim А мне понятно, что вы запутались в трех березах...

Answer (score 2):

Это самая обычная ситуация, с которой сталкиваются даже в таких организациях, как Майкрософт, Эпл и Гугл много раз в день. Пишут очень много полезного кода, а потом выясняется, что вчера, или на прошлой неделе, или даже много лет и версий операционных систем назад допустили ошибку.

Выход очень прост: нужно просто исправить эту ошибку в последней версии файла.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких ситуаций создана операция `git rebase`.

В зависимости от того как именно вы хотите поступить: просто удалить коммит "День 2" или исправить его, у вас два варианта действий.

Удалить коммит:

Выполнить интерактивный rebase всей ветки "День 1"..."День N", исключив из нее коммит "День 2". Может вызвать большое количество конфликтов, если правки начиная с "День 3" и далее пересекаются с правками "День 2".

Исправить:

Переключиться на коммит "День 2". Внести исправления, закоммитить их. Выполнить rebase всей ветки на коммит исправления.

PS Чтобы не потерять свои правки в процессе экспериментов заранее создайте на последнем коммите "День N" еще одну ветку или тэг. Если что-то пойдет не так, то сможете выполнить reset на нее, если всё удастся, то просто ее удалите. Я обычно создаю тэг с именем `save`